# Google Chart Timeline - Defining the range

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, timeline

Is it possible to define the range of the timeline chart?

I see that the range is automatically defined according to the data (**image 1**) but I would like to have a wider range even if there is no data to display (**image 2**).

## Image 1

[image]

## Image 2

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following chart options, provide a min and max date for the x-axis (`hAxis`)...

```
hAxis: {
  minValue: new Date(2018, 0, 1),  // example dates...
  maxValue: new Date(2018, 11, 1)
}
```

Comment: hope this helps -- options were introduced in [release version #: 43](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#october-2-2015)...